# mail doesnt show embed images properly on some browsers

Tags: html, ios, email, outlook, gmail

Here's the thing, I want to send some text and pictures in a email, but decide what image to use AFTER I send the e-mail (Yeah, it sounds pointless and confusing, but it isn't pointless for the use I want to give it, believe me) so this was my idea:
I send the mail in html format using an embed image like this (I'm gonna use a real image I'm trying to send):

```
<img src="http://rodrigophp.byethost15.com/CAS/1/Tex1.png">
```

After the mail is sent, I go to a web I programmed, and using some php the desired image gets copied to the "/CAS/1/" directory, and renamed to "Tex1.png".

It all worked just fine about half a year ago, when I opened the recieved mail (after I set what image I wanted, to avoid browser's cache) it all worked perfectly.

But recently I tried it again, and it works If I see the mail recieved in gmail:

[Gmail shows properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8xJw.jpg)

But when I open it in outlook website or from my iOS devices, images won't show (and yes, I have the "download images" setting activated in iOS):

[Outlook mail and iOS mail don't show the image (Tested on iPhone 5 and iPad 4 both iOS 9.2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8xJw.jpg)

I have no idea what's going on, it's like outlook web and iOS mail app can't access the URL, but it's clearly accesible for google mail web (but not if I open my gmail account in my mobile phone. The same mail, in the same account, can be seen on browser but can't be seen from Mail app.)

What's going on here? any ideas how to make it work? It worked perfectly for all of them about half a year ago!

Comment: Im having the same issue? Did you found the solution or any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry, no solution yet :S noone answers me, doesn't matter where I ask this. If you ever know how to solve this, please tell me!! I need this! hahaha